# Count number of comma-separated substrings inside single quotes in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've a string which is in the below format.
'abc','def','ghi' etc

I want to find the number of words in this string (words inside single quotes) using regex.

edit:
tried this, I think this works:

```
        int c = 0;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'[^*]'");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
        while(matcher.find()){
           c++;
        }
```

Comment: regex is not the best weapon of choice for this purpose

Comment: trying to learn regex :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you use a regexp to count ? 
You could use a str.split(",") and get the array size ?

Comment: Then you could use a match with something like `'[^']*'` Which look for `'` then X characters that are not `'` and finally another `'`

Comment: I don't think split is the right choice here. It is more powerful than needed. He simply wants to count the number of occurences of `,`...

Comment: @Murat You're right the overhead of creating the array wouldn't be needed.

Comment: @coder247 I'll give you the first free lesson of regex: don't use regex unless you HAVE to use regex.

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex

```
String regex = "your regular expression here";   // Regex that matches double words
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);     // Compile Regex
Matcher m = p.matcher("your upcoming string");         // Create Matcher
int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
  count++;
}
system.out.println("Number of match = "+count);
```

Using String

```
String str = "'abc','def','ghi'";

String wordsWithQuotes[] = str.split(",");
System.out.println("no of words = "+wordsWithQuotes.length);
```

or

```
System.out.println("no of words = "+str.split(",").length);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not regex but it works fast

```
int numberOfWords = (str.length() - str.replaceAll("'","").length()) / 2;
```